# Support for Apache 2.4

Tags: security, webserver

I have noted that CiviCRM creates .htaccess with the `Deny from all` command in stead of the `Require all denied`. This causes security issues with my new setup at a hosting site.

Drupal has support for both:

```
# Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

When is CiviCRM going to support Apache 2.4?

Comment: This is a good catch!  Are you able to submit a pull request for this improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is my first try using Github. Changed civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/File.php and committed to master branch with a proper summary and description. Change tag 875f1c8.

Do I have to do anything else? Should I enter anything in the issue list?

Comment: That's great! Could you edit your answer to link to provide a link to your pull request.

Comment: Well, I tried, but I am not used to do this. I created a JIRA issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21571

Comment: I have used GitHub Desktop to commit the change, but I cannot see the result in GitHub. I tried to create a pull request manually, but I am reluctant to go further in case I am messing things up .